# is application/x-www-form-urlencoded default for html form?

Tags: html, forms, enctype

I found out that HTML form supports only two enctype types. They are `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`. I understand that I use `multipart/form-data` when I need to upload a file. When do I use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Is it default form enctype?

Comment: Actually three: it also supports 
[text/plain](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/form/enctype).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, it is. Here's a cite from the [W3 HTML forms specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype):

> The default value for this attribute is `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. The value `"multipart/form-data"` should be used in combination with the [`INPUT`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-INPUT) element, `type="file"`.

The webbrowser will take care about [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) automatically.

Answer (score 9):

application/x-www-form-urlencoded

This is the default content type. Forms submitted with this content type must be encoded as follows:

1) Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by '+', and then reserved characters are escaped as described in [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by '%HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as "CR LF" pairs (i.e., `%0D%0A').

2) The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by '=' and name/value pairs are separated from each other by `&'.

Check out [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) link for more on form content types, or [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/references.html#ref-RFC2388) for more information about file uploads and such.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the default `enctype` is [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype).