# Flex File upload is not working in struts environment using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, apache-flex, file-upload, struts2

I am using a jsp for file upload using common-fileupload.It is working fine in spring blaze-ds and  flex environment. But the same jsp when I use in struts and flex framework I am getting the following error:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /pages/Template_Upload.jsp at line 69

```
66:             FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
67:             ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
68:             //List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
69:             List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
70:             out.println(items);
71:             int counter = 0;
72:             


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:505)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:398)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)



root cause 
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:850)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:779)
    org.apache.jsp.pages.Template_005fUpload_jsp._jspService(Template_005fUpload_jsp.java:202)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)


root cause 
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:908)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:331)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:351)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    org.apache.jsp.pages.Template_005fUpload_jsp._jspService(Template_005fUpload_jsp.java:136)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

Please help me..
Thanks in Advance

**UPDATED**
This is my JSP. I am getting items size as 0.So it is not entering the for loop and creating file in the specified path.

```
 String uploadpath = "C:\\XXXX\\XXXXX\\DataToUpload";
    uploadDir = uploadpath;
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    out.println(items);
    int counter = 0;
    for(FileItem item : items) {
        File uploadedFile = new File(uploadDir + File.separator + item.getName());
        uploadedFile.createNewFile();
        try 
         {
          item.write(uploadedFile);
         }
         catch(IOException e) {
           log.error("error" + e);
         }
      }
```

Comment: Does your form contain `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Comment: No my form doesnt contain enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

> No my form doesnt contain `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Then it's not a surprise that you are getting the error

> org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: **the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data** or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null

I don't know Flex file upload, but when uploading files, the content must be `multipart/form-data`.

If no content type is specified, the default one is used: [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2436725/1654265)

Comment: var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
  request.url = UPLOAD_URL;
   request.contentType="multipart/form-data";
   fr.upload(request);

Comment: This is my flex code.

private var fr:FileReference;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
request.url = UPLOAD_URL;
request.contentType="multipart/form-data";
fr.upload(request);
 
I am not aware of how to specify enctype="multipart/form-data" in flex forms.So I am sending request to JSP like this.
But I am getting the same error.
 
Also in JSP,
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
When I try to print items,I am getting the size as 0.

Comment: Can you post your JS and JSP (properly cleaned by private and unnecessary data) by editing your own question ?