# html form default enctype

Tags: html

What is HTML 5 Forms default enctype, when using 'post' method in the form?
I want to upload some files and I don't know if it works without adding the enctype property.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" [Info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is application/x-www-form-urlencoded default for html form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436716/is-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-default-for-html-form)